# Need Help Generating NULL Entries for Months with No Orders

Tags: sql, null, cumulative-sum

I have to create output that shows all fields from a table (Tbl) and create an additional column that calculates Cumulative Sum for each customer by month, (eg if a customer has two sales in April, the new column will have the Sum of those sales and any prior sales on both rows). That much I can do.

My issue is generating rows every month for every client **even when they have no sales**, and still having the cumulative column show the previous month's cumulative sum correctly.

Desired output:
[Picture Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyENl.png)

```
Customer_ID Order_ID    Order_Date  Order_Amt_Total_USD Month_ID    Cum_Total_By_Month
John        123        4/4/2019      30                  Jun-19          120
John        124        4/12/2019     90                  Jun-19          120
Mark       null         null        null                 Jun-19           0
Sally       150        4/20/2019     50                  Jun-19           50
John        null         null       null                 Jul-19           120
Mark        165        7/7/2019      80                  Jul-19           170
Mark        166        7/7/2019      90                  Jul-19           170
Sally       160        7/5/2019      75                  Jul-19           125
John        null        null         null                Aug-19           120
Mark        null        null         null                Aug-19           170
Sally       null        null         null                Aug-19           125
```

I'll list the code below, but this is a link to a SQL fiddle with sample data and the two queries of the pieces that i have working (with help from you wonderful people on this site). http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1d86b/11

I can generate the desired Cumulative running sum by customer and month using the first query.

I can also generate a base table that gives me a month_id for every customer for every month in the second query.

I need help making the combination of those two that will generate the desired output with the null rows for when months/Customers don't have any sales.

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
-- Generates cumulative total by month by Customer, but only shows when they have a sale
SELECT 
    Customer_ID, Order_Date, order_id, Order_Amt_Total_USD,
    to_char(date_trunc('month', Order_Date), 'Mon YYYY') AS mon_text,
    (Select 
     sum(Order_Amt_Total_USD) 
        FROM tbl t2
         WHERE t2.Customer_ID = t.Customer_ID
         AND date_trunc('month', t2.Order_Date) <= t.Order_Date ) AS Cumulative
FROM    tbl t
GROUP BY mon_text, Customer_ID, Order_Date, order_id, Order_Amt_Total_USD
ORDER BY date_trunc('month', Order_Date), Customer_ID, Order_Date
;

-- Generates Proper List of All Month IDs for each Customer from entered date through today
WITH temp AS (
   SELECT date_trunc('month', Order_Date) AS mon_id
  FROM tbl
  )
Select
Customer_ID,
to_char(mon_id, 'Mon YYYY') AS mon_text
From tbl,
generate_series('2015-01-01'::date, now(), interval '1 month') mon_id
LEFT  JOIN temp USING (mon_id)
GROUP BY mon_id,Customer_ID
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you can combine window functions with `generate_series()`:

```
SELECT c.Customer_ID, mon,
       SUM(Order_Amt_Total_USD) as month_total,
       SUM(SUM(Order_Amt_Total_USD)) OVER (PARTITION BY c.Customer_ID ORDER BY mon) as running_total
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Customer_Id FROM tbl) c CROSS JOIN
     generate_series('2015-01-01'::date, now(), interval '1 month') mon LEFT JOIN
     tbl t
     ON t.Customer_Id = c.customer_id and
        date_trunc('month', t.Order_Date) = mon
GROUP BY c.Customer_ID, mon
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1d86b/24) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thank so much! This got me most of the way there, just had to tweak some output formatting for my specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

Sample below shows how you can use partition by to achieve the output-

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (Order_ID varchar(10), Customer_ID varchar(10), Order_Date date, Order_Amt_Total_USD bigint);
    
INSERT INTO tbl (Order_ID, Customer_ID, Order_Date, Order_Amt_Total_USD)
VALUES
    ('100', 'qwe', '2015-08-04', 6),
    ('101', 'qwe', '2015-05-20', 7),
    ('102', 'qwe', '2015-04-08', 8),
    ('103', 'qwe', '2015-04-07', 9),
    ('109', 'aaa', '2015-04-28', 1),
    ('110', 'aaa', '2015-04-28', 2),
    ('111', 'aaa', '2015-05-19', 3),
    ('112', 'aaa', '2015-08-06', 4),
    ('113', 'aaa', '2015-08-27', 5),
    ('114', 'aaa', '2015-08-07', 6)
```

**Query**

```
select  Order_Date , Customer_ID, Order_Amt_Total_USD,
       sum(Order_Amt_Total_USD) over (partition by Customer_ID order by Order_Date) as cumulative
from tbl;
```